# IEEE: A survey or review paper?

Tags: ieee, review-articles

I am looking some papers published in IEEE which start with titles:

- A Survey of IOT
- Cloud Computing - A Survey

Are these also known as review papers? In other words, are they based on literature review or literature survey?

How does IEEE differentiate them?

Would you do a "literature review" for writing such survey papers? This is really confusing.

Comment: What data do they show? What references?

Comment: Survey is review of a field, so to say. So, literature review + lots of experience. But what's your actual question?

Comment: My question is about the confusing use of terms "survey" and "review" paper. Even when a paper says it's a survey on something, it is actually seems like a review. But in general I consider a survey to be shorter, lighter than a review. When applied to research papers it seems there's only a literature review. A research paper that says "A Survey on blah blah" is 25-30 pages and includes over 100 citations. So, If I am correct I should be doing a literature review even when I call the paper a survey?

Comment: You should look at the list of issues and their tables of contents of the ACM Computing Surveys journal. Nothing "light" about those papers and issues.